monaco-editor-nls is not working with monaco editor
I am using monaco-editor version 0.50.0 and monaco-editor-nls version 3.1.0 in angular project.
I want to give multiple language support to monaco-editor.
When I import from monaco-editor-nls/locale/zh-hans, I am receiving following errors:
Cannot find module 'monaco-editor-nls/locale/zh-hans' or its corresponding type declarations.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
